# I2C Bus writable/readable flags on I2C file descriptor

Tags: c++, linux, select, file-descriptor, i2c

I would like to connect multiple thermometers to a Raspberry board via the I2C bus on Raspbian, using a C++ application with an event loop containing `pselect()`. Opening the default `i2c-0` file descriptor (and using the [linux/i2c-dev.h](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/marcelo/linux-2.4/include/linux/i2c-dev.h) interface ) from the application, I'd add the file descriptor to `pselect()`'s `fd_set *readfds` and `fd_set *writefds`. I wonder if this file descriptor would ever become `FD_WRITEABLE` or `FD_READABLE` ? Since I2C is a master/slave setup, it should be impossible for a thermometer to initiate communication, because both the read and write operations are initiated by the application in userland, so I suppose `FD_READABLE` should be out of the question, am I right?

I haven't found anything about using the I2C with pselect, [what does readable/writable mean in a socket file descriptor? And why regular files don't bother with that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314547/what-does-readable-writable-mean-in-a-socket-file-descriptor-and-why-regular-fi]) was the closest answer I stumbled upon: "Readable means there is data or a FIN present in the socket receive buffer.
Writable means there is space available in the socket send buffer." Is an I2C device buffered? Can I depend on this mechanism?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's this:

> The pselect() and select() functions shall support regular files, terminal and pseudo-terminal devices, STREAMS-based files, FIFOs, pipes, and sockets. The behavior of pselect() and select() on file descriptors that refer to other types of file is unspecified.

The i2c-0 is a character device file type: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface

`pselect()` really doesn't guarantee anything for that file. So, no you can't depend on it.